# Hiding table data using <div style="display:none">

Tags: css, html

So, I've hidden whole tables like this, which works fine:

```
<div style="display:none">
<table>
<tr><th>Test Table</th><tr>
<tr><td>123456789</td><tr>
<tr><td>123456789</td><tr>
<tr><td>123456789</td><tr>
</table>
</div>
```

But I want to hide just a group of rows like this:

```
<table>
<tr><th>Test Table</th><tr>
<div style="display:none">
<tr><td>123456789</td><tr>
<tr><td>123456789</td><tr>
<tr><td>123456789</td><tr>
</div>
</table>
```

But that doesn't work.  Any hints?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `<tr>` cannot exist as a direct child to `<div>`. Also, `<div>` cannot exist as a direct child to `<tr>`

Comment: Try to put the style="display:none" in all the `<tr>` you want hidden. You can't put a `<div>` as a direct child of a table.

Comment: That's pretty much the point of the question, Simeon.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Just apply the style attribute to the tr tag. In the case of multiple tr tags, you will have to apply the style to each element, or wrap them in a tbody tag:

```
<table>
  <tr><th>Test Table</th><tr>
  <tbody style="display:none">
    <tr><td>123456789</td><tr>
    <tr><td>123456789</td><tr>
    <tr><td>123456789</td><tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 9):

Unfortuantely, as `div` elements can't be direct descendants of `table` elements, the way I know to do this is to apply the CSS rules you want to each `tr` element that you want to apply it to.

```
<table>
<tr><th>Test Table</th><tr>
<tr><td>123456789</td><tr>
<tr style="display: none; other-property: value;"><td>123456789</td><tr>
<tr style="display: none; other-property: value;"><td>123456789</td><tr>
<tr><td>123456789</td><tr>
<tr><td>123456789</td><tr>
</table>
```

If you have more than one CSS rule to apply to the rows in question, give the applicable rows a `class` instead and offload the rules to external CSS.

```
<table>
<tr><th>Test Table</th><tr>
<tr><td>123456789</td><tr>
<tr class="something"><td>123456789</td><tr>
<tr class="something"><td>123456789</td><tr>
<tr><td>123456789</td><tr>
<tr><td>123456789</td><tr>
</table>
```

Comment: IS it possible to apply this style to td?            like <tr><td style="display: none;">123456789</td><tr> ...?

Comment: What is `other-property`?

Answer (score 5):

Just set the display:none on the  elements that you want to hide:

```
<table>
<tr><th>Test Table</th><tr>
<tr style="display:none"><td>1. 123456789</td><tr>
<tr><td>2. 123456789</td><tr>
<tr><td>3. 123456789</td><tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<style type="text/css">
.hidden { display:none; }
</style>

<table>
<tr><th>Test Table</th><tr>
<tr class="hidden"><td>123456789</td></tr>
<tr class="hidden"><td>123456789</td></tr>
<tr class="hidden"><td>123456789</td></tr>
</table>
```

And instead of:

```
<div style="display:none;">
<table>...</table>
</div>
```

you had better use:
    ...

Answer (score 3):

Give all the rows you want to hide a class name that you can use for hiding. Use javascript to add/remove this class from the different rows.

```
<table>
<tr><th>Test Table</th><tr>
<tr class="toHide"><td>123456789</td><tr>
<tr class="toHide"><td>123456789</td><tr>
<tr class="toHide"><td>123456789</td><tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.toHide
{
 display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to have `div` tags between `tr` tags. You have to look for some other strategies like creating a CSS class with `display: none` and adding it to concerning rows or adding inline style `display: none` to concerning rows.

```
.hidden
{
  display:none;
}

<table>
  <tr><td>I am visible</td><tr>
  <tr class="hidden"><td>I am hidden using CSS class</td><tr>
  <tr class="hidden"><td>I am hidden using CSS class</td><tr>
  <tr class="hidden"><td>I am hidden using CSS class</td><tr>
  <tr class="hidden"><td>I am hidden using CSS class</td><tr>
</table>
```

**or**

```
<table>
  <tr><td>I am visible</td><tr>
  <tr style="display:none"><td>I am hidden using inline style</td><tr>
  <tr style="display:none"><td>I am hidden using inline style</td><tr>
  <tr style="display:none"><td>I am hidden using inline style</td><tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the sections you want to hide in their own tbody and dynamically show/hide that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can hide only the rows that you want to hide. This can be helpful if you want to show rows only when some condition is satisfied in the rows that are currently being shown. The following worked for me.

```
<table>
  <tr><th>Sample Table</th></tr>  
  <tr id="row1">
    <td><input id="data1" type="text" name="data1" /></td>
  </tr>
 <tr id="row2" style="display: none;">
    <td><input id="data2" type="text" name="data2" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="row3" style="display: none;">
    <td><input id="data3" type="text" name="data3" /></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

In CSS, do the following:

```
#row2{
    display: none;
}

#row3{
    display: none;
}
```

In JQuery, you might have something like the following to show the desired rows.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($("#row1").val() === "sometext"){  //your desired condition
        $("#row2").show();
    }

    if($("#row2").val() !== ""){   //your desired condition
        $("#row3").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `<div>`, it would be better to use to provide the `<tr>` (which you want to hide) an id and then hiding it using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

```
    

    /* add javascript*/
    {
    document.getElementById('abc 1').style.display='none';
    }
   /* after that add html*/
   
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>...</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table border = 2>
    <tr id = "abc 1">
    <td>abcd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id ="abc 2">
    <td>efgh</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add `style="display:none"` in any of `<tr>` that you want to hide.