# <div style display="none" > inside a table not working

Tags: html, css, dom

I am trying to toggle display of a div element which has a label and a textbox using javascript.
Here is the code snippet

```
<table id="authenticationSetting" style="display: none">
<div id="authenticationOuterIdentityBlock" style="display: none;">
                <tr>

                    <td class="orionSummaryHeader"><orion:message key="policy.wifi.enterprise.authentication.outeridentitity"/>: </td>
                    <td class="orionSummaryColumn">
                        <orion:textbox id="authenticationOuterIdentity" size="30"/>
                    </td>

                </tr>
                </div>

            </table>
```

However on page load the div element still displays ,the display toggling for the table element is working fine.
I am at a loss as to why this is not working,could it be that the style of the table element is overriding the style of the div element.
P.S. I am still able to hide elements inside the div but not the div itself.

Comment: Looks like you're putting a `div` where it shouldn't be; wrapped around a `tr` element.

Comment: `<div>` tag inside a `<table>` tag. syntax is not correct.

Comment: your html is invlid, table should have `tr` then `td`, inside `td` your content should be added

Comment: so u're saying div elements shouldn't be wrapping tr elements.
Is there any other way I could toggle display of a table row?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding table data using <div style="display:none">](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910349/hiding-table-data-using-div-style-displaynone)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

simply change `<div>` to `<tbody>`

```
<table id="authenticationSetting" style="display: none">
  <tbody id="authenticationOuterIdentityBlock" style="display: none;">
    <tr>
      <td class="orionSummaryHeader">
        <orion:message key="policy.wifi.enterprise.authentication.outeridentitity" />:</td>
      <td class="orionSummaryColumn">
        <orion:textbox id="authenticationOuterIdentity" size="30" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks
this works and so does <tr style="display:none;">
But this is screwing up the existing style of my table...wonder why that's happening

Comment: yes - correct, good solution but screwing up the layout of the table

Comment: visibility: hidden can be used (instead of display: none) if you want to hide an element, but you want it to still affect the layout as if it was not hidden.

Answer (score 6):

Semantically what you are trying is invalid html, `table` element cannot have a `div` element as a direct child. What you can do is, get your `div` element inside a `td` element and than try to hide it