# How would one make a slide show of text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I make a slide show of text?

For exemple, on my “about” page (for my brand), I have three different points, but I don’t want to have them all together so I have three different parts (still in my “about” section) and when someone presses “continue” or “next”, a new point is switched out with the first one (still in the “about” sub page).

Comment: Do you mean "javascript"?

Comment: @Lance yeah i was abbreviating, I can see how that can be confusing, I'll change it.

Comment: May https://speckyboy.com/css-javascript-text-animation-snippets/ will be helpful....

Comment: @TimothyKA It’s not “abbreviating”. Java and JavaScript are two completely different languages.

Comment: @Xufox I know lol, when i was typing the question it didnt come to mind. But it's fixed now :)

Answer (score -1):

This has been answered here: [Very Simple with Link Click Change the Content of a Div on a Single Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759812/very-simple-with-link-click-change-the-content-of-a-div-on-a-single-page)

Basically you want to use onclick events to toggle between versions of content for a div.

Comment: Why in the world is this answer downvoted?  It is exactly answered in the SO link provided.